# Two 'name' and 'value' in dir() output of python3.4 enum value

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I was trying out 'Enum' class in Python3.4, and I am having a problem understanding the output of 'dir()' when applied to an enum field. Example:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class SE(Enum):
...     cat = 10
...     dog = 20
...     elephant = 0
...     horse = 5
... 
>>> c = SE.dog
>>> type(c)
<enum 'SE'>
>>> dir(c)
['__class__', '__doc__', '__module__', 'name', 'name', 'value', 'value']
```

Why are there two 'name' and 'value' fields? 
Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 3.5.1. I get `['__class__', '__doc__', '__module__', 'name', 'value']`

Comment: That's weird, is it a bug then? 
My version: Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29)

Comment: Can't reproduce on Python 3.5.1 (Windows x64), nor on Python 3.4.2 (Debian).

Comment: My sys.version is showing:
'3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:28:29) \n[GCC 4.8.4]' (Using ubuntu 14.04, the default python3 that is available there)

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce using your version on Ubuntu. Most likely a bug then.

Comment: I can also reproduce on ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Looks that way. `dir()` is quite a tricky little function

Comment: Works fine on 3.5 though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed in [*93152:9038b63dad52*](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/9038b63dad52):

> Issue22506: remove name & value from `__dir__` as they now show up automatically

See [issue22506](http://bugs.python.org/issue22506).

Comment: Thanks, much better answer than 'As per the comments, this is most likely a bug' :P

Comment: @Akash1993: can you please unaccept my answer? I'm not entirely sure my analysis was correct.

Comment: Okay, but that changeset-link : https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/9038b63dad52 , handles this bug I think. Are you sure that it is not?

Comment: Oh, right.  And I see you said 'unaccept'.  *sigh* Okay, putting my reading glasses on.  On the bright side, your answer is correct.